# Solr/Lucene - partial fuzzy match

Tags: solr, lucene

How do you set up partial (substring) fuzzy match in Solr 4.2.1?

For example, if you have a list of US cities indexed, I would like a search term "Alber" to match "Alburquerque".

I have tried using the `NGramFilterFactory` on the `<fieldType>` and rebuilt the index but queries do not return results as expected - they still work as if I had just done the standard `text_general` defaults.  Exact matches work, and explicit fuzzy searches would work given sufficient similarity (for example "Alberquerque~" with one misspelling would work.)

I did go to the analyzer tool in the Solr admin and saw that my ngrams were indeed being generated.

Is there something i'm missing from the query side?

Or should I take a different approach altogether?

And can this work with dismax?  (Multiple fields indexed like this with different weights)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you n-gramming at query time as well?

Comment: No. Only at index.  I may have it working now after restarting Solr.  I thought reloading the core would be sufficient.  Is this a good approach in general?

Comment: Can you post your definition for the fieldType? Since you do n-gramming only at index time, `Alb` with match the tokens produced for `Alburquerque`, but not `Albur`.